# GStreamer: Intercept End of Stream Event and restart

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp

I'm implementing an RTSP server which reads a video H264 file stream and makes it available under RTSP protocol.
The idea is this:
The server creates a pipeline using video1.mp4 as videosrc and then, when video ends and the EOS event is generated, it has to switch filesrc to video2.mp4 and restart streaming automatically. When video2.mp4 ends it switches back to video1.mp4 again. The client is supposed to never stop receiving a video stream in this way.
Is it possible to obtain a server behavior like this?
Cheers